# there is a built-in feature that limits apps from background processing, where is it?

Tags: applications, background-process, optimization

So one night I got crazy and installed tons of apps that have background processing on my galaxy tab 8.0, they were draining its battery really fast. Android itself suggested to limit some of them to improve my battery life on the notifications tab, I tapped on that notification and limited some of them.

Now 2 weeks later I've found that my individual alarm app that I use doesn't ring anymore, I need to get access to that limiting feature  again to see if I have limited my alarm app or not, but I don't seem to find it anywhere in the settings. Googling doesn't help either because it only finds those articles that are advertising some background process limiting app indirectly.

I know uninstalling and reinstalling my alarm app or some other usual routines can fix the problem, but I need to know what exactly is causing its alarms to not go off to prevent it in the future, I can lose my job if I oversleep again.

Update : I've found out that it's a Samsung feature called "App optimisation", I'm guessing tab 8.0 isn't supposed to have that feature, so they have removed its shortcut from the settings, but not the actual feature from the os, and they forgot to disable the notification alert whenever there are a lot of apps with background processing, so that's why I had access to this feature earlier.
Now my question is, are there any other ways to access "app optimisation" other than through settings under the battery tab? Because it's not there for me.

Update #2:It alerted me again so I took a screenshot before closing it.I haven't found any other way to get access to this feature yet.

[image: this]

Comment: When you tapped on notification which app opened settings or something else? Try finding privacy guard under security in settings. Or open app in settings maybe there you have option run in background.

Comment: I have found out that its samsung's "app optimisation" , but the weird thing is galaxy tab 8.0 isnt suppose to have that feature, so its not accessible through settings. Lol

Answer (score 0):

This is an option under Developer Options. To enable it:

1. *Settings*
2. *About Device* (may be under *More* tab)
3. Tap the *Build Number* 7 times

Once enabled, you can find Developer Options in Settings. If you scroll down near the bottom there should be an option for *Limit Background Processes*. Usually, there is no limit, but this might be your answer.

Comment: I've already looked that up, its set on standard limit. Read the update on my post, I already know what it was, but i dont have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have Android 10 now, and when my battery & data was being eaten up faster, I googled what to do about it & this is what worked. ( It works also for abndroid 9, however not certain about previous versions)

1. You must turn off phone optimisation... ie. just dont use it because each time it resets apps. First go to settings & type in "adaptive battery: there you will find you can open your list of all apps including system apps by clicking on the 3 dots to the right. There you can turn off backround for every app, except "phone" & " messages" isnt an option. ( Cannot be turned off).
   There, under adaptive battery, you will also find  an option for "power saving exclusions";
2. You will see "Battery Saver"; turn it off if it is on.
3. You will see " Power Saving Exclusions: open it & DO NOT turn any on to exclude ( yes, seems strange!) You will notice some apps in the list are turned on and whited out, which means theh are necessary to run the phone. ... (The problem with using " battery optimization" or " exclusion" is that it automatically resets all apps back to using background data.)
   Now, over time, some apps wont work correctly, and I found I had to turn "on" background data because it is used for that app. P. S. I used to go the way of " developer options" and it messed up every time. However, it may help for previous android editions.
   The second way on Android 9 & 10 at least is to got settings and open up each app... there, click on " data usage, turn off "background data". Then click on "battery usage, and turn ON "restrict data in the background".

- Note... whenever you have to reset network settings for any reason, these background settings reset, so you do have to check adaptive battery settings. This is the same reason I was given and found true, that using " battery optimization isnt good: it resets background settings!!
  * Also note to check these settings when installing new apps. I often forget!
  Thanks for listening. HOPE IT HELPS!!